# Json decode with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I have a question about reading a json using flutter

The code below returns in the string `value` -> `{"return": 2}`. But when I print the `valuemap.values` ​​I have the following result: `(2)`.

How do I do it to read only the integer value?
,

**Dart Code:**

```
Future<int> login(String Email, String Password) async {
    //Ret rappresenta il valore di ritorno della funzione 
    var ret=0;
    Map map={
      'Username': Email,
      'Password':Password
    };
    String value=await apiRequest("/login", map);
    print("Valore prima del parse:" +value);
    Map valueMap = json.decode(value);
    print("Stampa di valore:" + valueMap.values.toString());
    return ret;
  }
```

Comment: Try that: `print("Stampa di valore:" + valueMap['return'].toString());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
...

Map valueMap = json.decode(value);
int returnValue = valueMap["return"];
print("Stampa di valore: $returnValue");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are successful to get the  string then you just access it valueMap["valuMap"] and assign to integer value